# Single correlation heatmap in "R" with two different correlation matrix but same row names

Tags: r

i am trying to make correlation heatmap in "R with two different correlation matrix. Lower triangle should correspond to different matrix and upper triangle to different. Suppose i have 100 genes and i did Microarray and transcriptome. Now i want to plot both in a single heatmap but in different triangles. 
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by first creating a correlation matrix that combines the two different triangles you want to use, and then plotting the heatmap from your combined correlation matrix.

First, I'll generate two data sets of random data, so we will have two correlation matrices to combine.

```
set.seed(24601)
# generate random data for first correlation matrix
m <- matrix(runif(25, min = -1, max = 1), ncol = 5)
cov1 <- m %*% t(m) # make it symmetrical and positive definite
df1 <- mnormt::rmnorm(n = 100, varcov = cov1, sqrt=NULL)  
colnames(df1) <- paste("X", 1:5, sep = "_")
# generate random data for second correlation matrix
m <- matrix(runif(25, min = -1, max = 1), ncol = 5)
cov2 <- m %*% t(m) 
df2 <- mnormt::rmnorm(n = 100, varcov = cov2, sqrt=NULL) 
colnames(df2) <- paste("X", 1:5, sep = "_")
```

Get the two correlation matrices:

```
cor1 <- cor(df1)  
cor2 <- cor(df2)
```

Combine the upper triangle from one correlation matrix with the lower from the other:

```
cor_combined <- cor1
cor_combined[upper.tri(cor_combined)] <- cor2[upper.tri(cor2)]
diag(cor_combined) <- NA # remove diagonal for better plotting (optional)
```

Plotting the heatmap, shown here using `ggplot2`. Since `ggplot()` generally works best with data in long format, I used `gather` to reformat the data --- the first six lines of the data frame used for plotting are shown after the `head()` command.

```
cor_df <- as.data.frame(cor_combined) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(var1 = row.names(.)) %>% 
  tidyr::gather("var2", "value", -var1) 

> head(cor_df)
  var1 var2       value
1  X_1  X_1          NA
2  X_2  X_1 -0.62115508
3  X_3  X_1  0.65660075
4  X_4  X_1 -0.24248121
5  X_5  X_1 -0.67412086
6  X_1  X_2 -0.01013485

ggplot(cor_df, aes(var1, var2)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "white") + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "darkred", high = "navy") + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

[image: heatmap from two different correlation matrices]